# How can I stop the confirmation to evaluate source code when exporting to html?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I have an org document that contains a lot of source code snippets in it. I want the results of the code to be exported when exporting to Html. On export Emacs asks me if I want to evaluate the code block on my system once for every bit of source code. This is a lot of questions.

Is there any way to stop Emacs for asking for confirmation every time?

The exact message is

> "Evaluate this goban code block on your system? (y or n)"

Note goban is the babel language I am exporting. (It is actually an image of a go board).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`org-confirm-babel-evaluate` can be set to `nil` to disable confirmation.

From the [documentation](http://orgmode.org/manual/Code-evaluation-security.html#Code-evaluation-security):

> Source code blocks
>
> Source code blocks can be evaluated during export, or when pressing
>        ‘C-c C-c’ in the block.  The most important thing to realize here
>        is that Org mode files which contain code snippets are, in a
>        certain sense, like executable files.  So you should accept them
>        and load them into Emacs only from trusted sources—just like you
>        would do with a program you install on your computer.
>
> Make sure you know what you are doing before customizing the
>        variables which take off the default security brakes.
>
> ```
> -- User Option: org-confirm-babel-evaluate
>       When t (the default), the user is asked before every code
>       block evaluation.  When ‘nil’, the user is not asked.  When
>       set to a function, it is called with two arguments (language
>       and body of the code block) and should return t to ask and
>       ‘nil’ not to ask.
> ```

As suggested by @Emmanuel Goldstein, the `:eval` header argument can be used for finer control.  It can be set to refuse evaluation, ask confirmation, directly evaluate, for each source block.

From the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html#index-eval_002c-header-argument):

> The `:eval` header argument can limit evaluation of specific code
>   blocks.  It is useful for protection against evaluating untrusted `src`
>   code blocks by prompting for a confirmation.  This protection is
>   independent of the ‘org-confirm-babel-evaluate’ setting.
>
> - ‘never or no’
>      Org will never evaluate this ‘src’ code block.
> - ‘query’
>      Org prompts the user for permission to evaluate this ‘src’ code
>      block.
> - ‘never-export or no-export’
>      Org will not evaluate this ‘src’ code block when exporting, yet the
>      user can evaluate this source block interactively.
> - ‘query-export’
>      Org prompts the user for permission to export this ‘src’ code
>      block.
>
> If `:eval` header argument is not set for a source block, then Org
>   determines whether to evaluate from the `org-confirm-babel-evaluate`
>   variable.

Comment: Will this be the same as using eval never-export on the header line of the code?

Comment: I don't know what it's supposed to do. Do you have a pointer to documentation?

Comment: https://orgmode.org/manual/Exporting-Code-Blocks.html

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein  never-export will refuse to evaluate when exporting, while setting org-confirm-babel-evaluate to nil will do it without asking for confirmation.

Comment: Thanks. All clear now.

Comment: I lack the energy in this moment to write up an answer with full details, so just tacking on a comment that one thing one can do is write a customized function for `org-confirm-babel-evaluate` to still prompt, but cache the results of the prompting on a per-file basis, either temporarily (while emacs is running) or even to be saved in a file and referenced.  For example, I have one set up that it'll prompt me every `n` seconds (for arbitrary `n`, I have mine at 1800) per file, but with each export also resetting the counter, so repeated exports won't prompt unless I take a half hour break.

Comment: Am I mistaken, or is there no `:eval always` or `:eval no-query` option that always executes the code block in question upon `C-c C-c` without asking.  I'd like to use that for Bash code blocks: I've turned on confirmation for the execution of Bash code blocks globally, because I don't want any stupid accidents to happen, but every now and then I'd like to execute a few without answering `yes` all the time (especially with multiple blocks in a session)...

Comment: Here's a way to add an `:eval yes` option to do exactly that: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/75110/17538